# Deleted all partitions from Mac mini except Boot Camp, now can't reinstall OS X

Tags: macos, bootcamp, install

I have a Mac Mini without DVD drive (2010), and I used Boot Camp to install Windows 8.

Everything worked but after I played in Windows with the partitions (I wanted to expand the partition of the Mac). I made mistake and deleted every partition (even Recovery HD) except from my Boot Camp partition. Since then, my Mac mini only boots into Windows. I can't install OS X now.

I took from my friend an OS X Install DVD and Application Install DVD (he also has a Mac mini). Then I took my PC's external USB DVD drive and connected to Mac mini, inserted the OS X install disk and powered on. During the power on I held the ⌘C button and I saw HDD "BOOTCAMP" and CD "OS X INSTALL" so I selected the CD but after that I only see the gray screen with an Apple logo.

How can I install OS X again on my Mac?

Comment: Sounds like your DVD is either bad or you are terribly impatient (how long did you wait?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Internet Recovery. Boot with ⌘⌥R until you get a spinning globe, then follow the instructions.

<sup>You'll need to have been fully up-to-date with Firmware updates though.</sup>

Comment: he said he nuked the recovery partition

Comment: Internet Recovery is different from the recovery partition.  If there is no recovery partition, or it can't be used, Internet Recovery boots just enough from EFI to get a network, and then it will download an image to start a recovery.

Comment: @AlanShutko thanks, I didn't know that internet recovery could function that way. My mistake.